# iPhone: Show image sequence as a VR

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, ipad, touch

I need to use a image sequence as a VR on the iOS. Is there component on the OS that does that? If not, is there any third party view for that? I'm very interested on learning more about it!

Thanks!

Comment: It's basically the exploration of objects through images taken at multiple viewing angles.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question to explain this, dont leave it in the comments.

Comment: Think about a panorama made from a image sequence.'

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a tutorial to create your own OpenGL (iOS or Android) VR engine.](http://phoenixdesign.fr/tutoriels/mobile/ios/immersion-vr.)
The principle is to create a 3D skybox where you will have to apply your images to create your environment.

There are some libraries ready to use too like this one : [Open AR](http://openar.net/)